# How to make objects exempt from SKcameranode movement

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm currently developing a scrolling platformer game, and I was wondering how I could have the joystick object move along with the screen but still be useable. Ive tried a number of things, but none of them have produced any viable options. At the moment, the joystick is usable but will scroll off the screen with the rest of the map.

Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
var map = SKNode()
var idleFrames = [SKTexture]()
var walkFrames = [SKTexture]()
var idleFrames1 = [SKTexture]()
var walkFrames1 = [SKTexture]()
var attackFrames1 = [SKTexture]()
var idling = 0
var bullets = 0
var bullet = SKSpriteNode()
var leaf = SKEmitterNode()
var hud: SKSpriteNode?


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var sp33d: CGVector = CGVectorMake(0.0,0.0)
    var knock: CGVector = CGVectorMake(-10.0, 0.0)
    var knock1: CGVector = CGVectorMake(10.0, 0.0)
    var jsp33d: CGFloat = 170
    var gameStick: Joystick?
    var player: SKSpriteNode?
    var ground: SKSpriteNode?
    var ground2: SKSpriteNode?
    var ground3: SKSpriteNode?
    var canJump = false
    var specialbutton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "special")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        hud = self.childNodeWithName("hud") as? SKSpriteNode
        gameStick = Joystick()
        gameStick?.createJoystick(hud!.frame.width/4, nameBack: "joystick", nameMoving: "joystick1")
        gameStick!.backPart!.zPosition = 4
        gameStick!.movingPart!.zPosition = 5
        map.addChild(gameStick!.backPart!)
        map.addChild(gameStick!.movingPart!)

        self.addChild(map)

        player = self.childNodeWithName("player") as? SKSpriteNode
        ground = self.childNodeWithName("testGround") as? SKSpriteNode
        ground2 = self.childNodeWithName("testGround2") as? SKSpriteNode
        player?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category.player
        ground?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category.ground
        ground2?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = category.ground
        player?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = category.ground
        ground?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = category.player
        player!.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 70)

        specialbutton.position = CGPointMake(600, 83)
        specialbutton.xScale = 0.165
        specialbutton.yScale = 0.165
        specialbutton.alpha = 0.5
        map.addChild(specialbutton)

        camera = self.childNodeWithName("camera") as? SKCameraNode
        camera?.position = player!.position

        if charnumber == 2{
        player?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sarah")
        }

        let idleAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "idle.atlas")
        var idleframes = [SKTexture]()
        for var i=1; i<=4; i++ {
            let idleframe = "JohnIdle\(i)"
            idleframes.append(idleAtlas.textureNamed(idleframe))
        }
        idleFrames = idleframes

        let walkAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "jrun.atlas")
        var walkframes = [SKTexture]()
        for var i=1; i<=8; i++ {
            let walkframe = "Johnrun\(i)"
            walkframes.append(walkAtlas.textureNamed(walkframe))
        }
        walkFrames = walkframes

        let idleAtlas1 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Sarahidle.atlas")
        var idleframes1 = [SKTexture]()
        for var i=1; i<=4; i++ {
            let idleframe1 = "SarahIdle\(i)"
            idleframes1.append(idleAtlas1.textureNamed(idleframe1))
        }
        idleFrames1 = idleframes1

        let walkAtlas1 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Sarahrun.atlas")
        var walkframes1 = [SKTexture]()
        for var i=1; i<=8; i++ {
            let walkframe1 = "Sarahrun\(i)"
            walkframes1.append(walkAtlas1.textureNamed(walkframe1))
        }
        walkFrames1 = walkframes1

        let attackAtlas1 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "sattack.atlas")
        var attackframes1 = [SKTexture]()
        for var i=1; i<=9; i++ {
            let attackframe1 = "sattack\(i)"
            attackframes1.append(attackAtlas1.textureNamed(attackframe1))
        }
        attackFrames1 = attackframes1

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -10.0)
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact) {
        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == category.player) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == category.ground) {
            idling = 0
            johnmove()
            print("hit")
            canJump = true
        }else{
        }
    }

    func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == category.player) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == category.ground) {
            canJump = false

        }
    }

    func bulletfire(){
        bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet1")
        leaf = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "leafParticle")!
        bullets = bullets + 1
        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(0.1, 0.1))
        bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = category.ground
        bullet.xScale = 0.016
        bullet.yScale = 0.016
        bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.addChild(bullet)
        self.addChild(leaf)
        if player?.xScale == 1{
            bullet.xScale = -0.016
            bullet.position.x = (player?.position.x)! + 21.5
            bullet.position.y = (player?.position.y)! + 15.4
            bullet.physicsBody?.velocity = (CGVectorMake(1000.0, 0.0))
        }else{
            bullet.position.x = (player?.position.x)! - 21.5
            bullet.position.y = (player?.position.y)! + 15.4
            bullet.physicsBody?.velocity = (CGVectorMake(-1000.0, 0.0))
        }
        let action = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1), SKAction.removeFromParent()])
        bullet.runAction(action, completion: {bullets = bullets - 1})
        leaf.runAction(action)
    }

    func move(){
        if player?.xScale ==  1 {
            player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
            player?.position.x = (player?.position.x)! - 20
        }else{
            player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
            player?.position.x = (player?.position.x)! + 20

        }

    }

    func johnmove() {
        if charnumber == 1 {
            if idling == 1 {
                player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
                player?.removeActionForKey("idle")
                player?.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(walkFrames, timePerFrame: 0.12, resize: false, restore: true)),withKey: "walk")
            }
            else if idling == 0 {
                player?.removeActionForKey("walk")
                player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
                player?.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(idleFrames, timePerFrame: 0.6, resize: false, restore: true)),withKey: "idle")
            }else if idling == 2 {
                player?.removeActionForKey("walk")
                player?.removeActionForKey("idle")
                player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
                player?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "JohnJump.png")
            }
        }else{
            sarahhmove()
        }
    }

    func sarahhmove() {
        if idling == 1 {
            player?.removeActionForKey("idle1")
            player?.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(walkFrames1, timePerFrame: 0.12, resize: true, restore: true)),withKey: "walk1")
        }
        else if idling == 0 {
            player?.removeActionForKey("walk1")
            player?.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(idleFrames1, timePerFrame: 0.6, resize: false, restore: true)),withKey: "idle1")
        }else if idling == 2 {
            player?.removeActionForKey("wal1k")
            player?.removeActionForKey("idle1")
            player?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "SarahJump.png")
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            var nodeTouched = SKNode()
            nodeTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
            if nodeTouched.name == "joystick1" {
                gameStick?.movingPart?.position = location
                if location.x > gameStick!.backPart!.position.x + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.width/2{
                    gameStick?.movingPart?.position = CGPointMake(gameStick!.backPart!.position.x + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.width/2, gameStick!.movingPart!.position.y)
                }
                if location.y > gameStick!.backPart!.position.y + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.height/2{
                    gameStick?.movingPart?.position = CGPointMake(gameStick!.movingPart!.position.x, gameStick!.backPart!.position.y + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.height/2)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        for touch in (touches ) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            var nodeTouched = SKNode()
            nodeTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
            if nodeTouched.name == "joystick1" {
                gameStick?.movingPart?.position = location
                if location.x > gameStick!.backPart!.position.x + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.width/2{
                    gameStick?.movingPart?.position = CGPointMake(gameStick!.backPart!.position.x + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.width/2, gameStick!.movingPart!.position.y)
                }
                if location.y > gameStick!.backPart!.position.y + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.height/2{
                    gameStick?.movingPart?.position = CGPointMake(gameStick!.movingPart!.position.x, gameStick!.backPart!.position.y + gameStick!.backPart!.frame.height/2)
                }
            }else if idling == 0 && charnumber == 2{
                player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
                player?.removeAllActions()
                if player?.xScale ==  1 {
                    player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
                    player?.position.x = (player?.position.x)! + 20
                }else{
                    player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
                    player?.position.x = (player?.position.x)! - 20
                }
                player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
                player?.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(attackFrames1, timePerFrame: 0.09, resize: true, restore: true),count: 1),completion: {self.move()})
                    player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
                player?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Sarah")
            }else if charnumber == 1 && idling == 0{
                player?.removeAllActions()
                bulletfire()
                let yrand = (arc4random_uniform(100) + 50)
                let xrand = (arc4random_uniform(300) + 80)
                let cartridge = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "casing")
                cartridge.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(0.1, 0.1))
                cartridge.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = category.ground
                cartridge.xScale = 0.05
                cartridge.yScale = 0.05
                cartridge.zPosition = 3
                cartridge.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.5
                let spin = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:0.6)
                cartridge.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spin))
                cartridge.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
                let flash = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "muzzleFlash")
                if player?.xScale == 1{
                    leaf.xScale = -1
                    flash?.position.x = (player?.position.x)! + 40
                    flash?.position.y = (player?.position.y)! + 15.3
                    cartridge.position.x = (player?.position.x)! + 27
                    cartridge.position.y = (player?.position.y)! + 15.3
                    player?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(knock)
                    cartridge.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(-CGFloat(yrand), CGFloat(xrand))
                }else{
                    flash?.position.x = (player?.position.x)! - 40
                    flash?.position.y = (player?.position.y)! + 15.3
                    flash?.xAcceleration = -5000
                    cartridge.position.x = (player?.position.x)! - 27
                    cartridge.position.y = (player?.position.y)! + 15.3
                    player?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(knock1)
                    cartridge.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(yrand), CGFloat(xrand))
                }
                flash?.zPosition = 3
                flash?.xScale = 0.15
                flash?.yScale = 0.15
                self.addChild(flash!)
                self.addChild(cartridge)
                let action = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.15), SKAction.removeFromParent()])
                let action1 = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5), SKAction.removeFromParent()])
                flash?.runAction(action)
                cartridge.runAction(action1)
                johnmove()
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            var nodeTouched = SKNode()
            nodeTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
            if nodeTouched.name == "joystick1" {
                let act = SKAction.moveTo(gameStick!.backPart!.position, duration: 0.2)
                gameStick?.movingPart?.runAction(act)
            }
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        hud!.position = (camera?.position)!
        let action = SKAction.moveTo((player?.position)!, duration: 0.01)
        camera!.runAction(action)
        player?.size = CGSizeMake(80,80)
        leaf.position = bullet.position
        print(canJump)
        if (sp33d.dx > 1.5 || sp33d.dx < -1.5) && idling != 1 && idling != 2 {
            idling = 1
            johnmove()
        }else if sp33d.dx < 0.1 && sp33d.dx > -0.1 && idling != 0  && idling != 2{
            idling = 0
            johnmove()
        }
        if sp33d.dx > 0.1 {
            player!.xScale = 1
        } else if sp33d.dx < -0.1 {
            player!.xScale = -1
        }

        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        let vX = gameStick!.movingPart!.position.x - gameStick!.backPart!.position.x

        let vY: CGFloat = gameStick!.movingPart!.position.y

        if  vY > gameStick!.backPart!.position.y + 20 && canJump == true{
            sp33d = CGVectorMake(vX/13, jsp33d)
            idling = 2
            johnmove()
        }else{
            sp33d = CGVectorMake(vX/13, 0)
        }
        player?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(sp33d)
    }

}
```

This is the class in which the joystick is created:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class Joystick: UIView {

    var movingPart: SKSpriteNode?
    var backPart: SKSpriteNode?

    let speed: CGFloat = 0.4

    var joyStickCenter: CGPoint?

    func createJoystick(dimensions: CGFloat, nameBack: String, nameMoving: String)
    {
        backPart = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "joystick")
        backPart?.size = CGSizeMake(dimensions, dimensions)
        backPart?.position = CGPoint(x: backPart!.size.width/2, y: backPart!.size.width/2)
        backPart?.name = nameBack
        backPart?.alpha = 0.4

        movingPart = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "joystick")
        movingPart?.size = CGSizeMake(dimensions*0.5, dimensions*0.5)
        movingPart?.position = backPart!.position
        movingPart?.name = nameMoving
        movingPart?.alpha = 0.8

        joyStickCenter = backPart!.position
    }

    func getDistance(p1: CGPoint, p2: CGPoint) -> Double
    {
        let firstPow = p2.x-p1.x
        let secondPow = p2.y-p1.y
        var squaredAdded = pow(firstPow, 2)
        squaredAdded += pow(secondPow, 2)
        let theSquirt = sqrt(Double(squaredAdded))

        return theSquirt
    }

    func resetMovingPart()
    {
        movingPart?.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(joyStickCenter!, duration: 0.4))
    }

    func calcXYDiff(loc: CGPoint) -> CGPoint
    {
        let oldMovingPartPoint = movingPart?.position
        movingPart?.position = loc
        if movingPart!.position.x-joyStickCenter!.x > backPart!.frame.width/2
        {
            movingPart?.position.x = oldMovingPartPoint!.x
        }
        if movingPart!.position.y-joyStickCenter!.y > backPart!.frame.height/2
        {
            movingPart?.position.y = oldMovingPartPoint!.y
        }
        let x = loc.x - joyStickCenter!.x
        let y = loc.y - joyStickCenter!.y
        return CGPoint(x: x*speed, y: y*speed)
    }
```

Any help would be greaty appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hope you figure this one out! i am attempting to fix the same issue lol

Comment: I have figured this out actually, you have to make the joystick the child of the the camera node, and make the joystick track on the camera node rather than the scene.

Comment: ahh. nice job thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the resetMovingPart() in your update() func.